Define this step function over the rational numbers
In desmos I plotted a step function (I only plotted 30% of it). Here is my graph:
This function is a function from $\Bbb Q\cap (0,1) \to \Bbb Q\cap(0,1).$
The step function is generated by counting the number of red curves less than a given green curve. So I started at the origin and worked my way up along the diagonal counting and plotting each point. I sort of view the green curves to be like an evenly spaced distribution of numbers whereas the red curves are a random one.
The red curves are given by
$$ R_s(x)=\bigg \lbrace    \exp \bigg( \frac{\log^2(\mathrm{random}(s))}{
\log x}  \bigg)  : s\in \Bbb R \cap (0,1)  \bigg \rbrace $$
and $0<x<1$. So in my plot I picked a number of curves i.e. cardinality of $|s|=100$.
The green curves are given by
$$G_t(x)=\bigg \lbrace    \exp \bigg( \frac{\log^2(t)}{
\log x}  \bigg)  : t\in \Bbb Q\cap(0,1)  \bigg \rbrace$$
where $t=\big \lbrace .01,.02,.03,...,.99 \big\rbrace.$ This just means there are $99$ green curves and $100$ red curves. Important note is that $t$ must be evenly spaced, i.e. the differences are the same value, here it is $.01$.
Since the difference between all the elements in $t$ are equal to $.01$ I will count a red  curve less than a green curve as $.01$ units. For example, in my desmos code I plot the first point as $(.01,0)$ because the first green curve has zero red curves less than it. Next I plot the point $(.02,.01)$ because the second green curve has one red curve less than it. And so on.
My question is:

How do you define this function as the number of curves tends to infinity? What does a plot of this function look like for $1,000$ curves?

The strange thing about this function is that even at infinity the step function will continue to only take on rational values and "oscillate" above and below the identity but won't converge to the identity. I wonder what dimension this step function at infinity has.
Here is a screenshot taken from the desmos plot:


Since the red numbers are chosen randomly, there isn't a single "What does a plot of this function look like for $1,000$ curves?"  There would be a probability density of curves, each of which is a realization of the random process for the red numbers.  The support for this prob. dens. is, as you say, a grid of points (and line segments of angles $0$, $\pi/4$, and $\pi/2$, if we choose to include those in the plot, although strictly they're not part of the realization).  I expect that the limit is the $\pi/4$ line. [cont.]

... I suspect that the curve approaches the identity as fast as the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test does for discrete samples drawn from the continuous (green's) cumulative density function.
